# How to add methods inside FLASK file?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, routes, apache-superset

I cloned the superset code in local and there was already a FLASK server file named app.py ,
app.py

```
def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = SupersetApp(__name__)

    try:
        # Allow user to override our config completely
        config_module = os.environ.get("SUPERSET_CONFIG", "superset.config")
        app.config.from_object(config_module)

        app_initializer = app.config.get("APP_INITIALIZER", SupersetAppInitializer)(app)
        app_initializer.init_app()
        print('Hello world')
        return app

    # Make sure that bootstrap errors ALWAYS get logged
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.exception("Failed to create app")
        raise ex
```

and I tried adding another function inside the same file but not gets called from the react end,

new function

```
api = Flask(__name__)
@api.route('/api/profile')
def my_profile(): 
    response_body = {
        "name": "Nagato",
        "about" :"Hello! I'm a full stack developer that loves python and javascript"
    }

    return response_body
```

But it shows http://localhost:8088/api/profile 404 not found error.

Note : I am new to react.js .So, forgive me if my question is very dumb..

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@api.route('/profile')` with `@api.route('/api/profile')`.
Or change your `react` http request url to `/profile` not `/api/profile`.

Comment: I have edited the question with clearer code. My doubt is , whether this error happening because of any wrong initialization of flask name?